# Asymptotically Periodic Potentials

Tags: mathematicians, differential-geometry, differential-equations, functional-analysis

Who came up with the idea of solving elliptic equations with periodic potentials and from there solving elliptic equations with asymptotically periodic potentials? I heard it was Pierre Louis Lions, but I found no records.

Comment: Are you referring to [the method of asymptotic homogenization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_homogenization#The_method_of_asymptotic_homogenization)? It was developed by Lions and his students, among others, see e.g. Asymptotic Analysis for Periodic Structures (1978) by Bensoussan, Lions, and Papanicolaou.

Comment: Could you give references for this method in your question please ?

Comment: For example in the Tang's paper: https://www.hindawi.com/journals/aaa/2014/607078/

Comment: This paper explicitly references [Lions's paper on the concentration compactness principle](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0294144916304280).

Comment: Conifold, but in this Lions paper I did not find him dealing with periodic and asymptotically periodic cases.

Comment: But the book does, doesn't it? And you should put @ in front of the username for the user to be notified of your comment.